# How to use the value in a variable as a object name to apply method to it"

Tags: python, object, pyqt

I made an app for my job using PyQt5. It runs on a touch screen so when I click on a textbox, it sends the name of that textbox in a variable (as a string). Then it "summons" an onscreen keyboard. I enter the value and when I press "ok" it checks the variable to know which textbox summoned the keyboard, and then sends the value to that textbox. I have a lot of textboxes. So now what I do is for each tb I will use

```
if variable = "textbox1":  
    window1.textbox1.setText(KeyboardValue)
```

What I'd like to do is:

```
window1.variable.setText(keyboardValue)
```

so it will use the object name stored in variable. But it just exits with exit code -6, without any explanation. I know there is a method called `sender()`, but I tried it with the same result.

Comment: use `getattr(window1, variable).setText(KeyboardValue)`

Answer (score 0):

You store a reference to `window1.textbox1` in a variable, and then you can access `setText` from that variable.

```py
textbox = window1.textbox1

# Elsewhere...

textBox.setText(keyboardValue)
```